# Navigation to next page in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

On button click I want to navigate to next page. My storyboard id = first AND class = ViewController where i want to navigate its storyboard id = next and class = second. how to navigate to it. how to do it in objective c??

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: i dont know how to do it in objective c?? As i know in swift ?? dont have idea

Comment: let nextcontroller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "next") as! second
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextcontroller, animated: true)

Comment: Brother! First of all, welcome to Stackoverflow. Before asking any questions in this forum. Try to search first, if not getting anything what you're looking for. Then, shoot your question here. 

Also, read the FAQ of Stackoverflow before posting questions.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but i am not getting any answers from here. . And i read all questions and answers related to it . . . :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In Obj-C**

```
//Write here your's storyboard name
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"myNewStoryboard" bundle:nil];
//Now write your next view controller and write your storyboard id.
MyNewViewController *myNewVC = (MyNewViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyNewViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myNewVC animated:YES];
```

**In Swift**

```
//Write here your's storyboard name
let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "myNewStoryboard", bundle: nil)
 //Now write your next view controller and write your storyboard id.
let myNewVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyNewViewController") as? MyNewViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(myNewVC!, animated: true)
```

Comment: Not works for me . . .

Comment: @SagarMahajan - he answered the example , you need to customize based on your class and identifir name

Comment: @SagarMahajan - accept any one answer if it is usefuul

Comment: Thanks Vivek , it is working for me

Comment: Give him upVote @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: @vivek  - if you copy and paste the code, please mention where you copied and mention the reference